# How would I make a cron job stop and start again?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab, cronjob

I am trying to make a cron job that stops at 12am today(friday) then start again Monday at 7am, what would the script for this look like, I am new to cron jobs.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445088/cron-job-start-and-stop-at-certain-time

Comment: This post isn't really a tutorial. There are heaps of better documents to be found. Keep on searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * /bin/timeout -s 2 10 /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Above kills after 10 minutes.

"12am today (Friday) then start again on Monday at 7am" - This looks more like a SERVICE than a cron job. However it is possible to assign a PID to this long cron job and add another cron job to kill this PID of the first.

The `* * * * *` from left to right:
Minute (Numeric) | Hour (Numeric) | Day of Month (Numeric) | Month (Numeric) | Day of the Week (0=Sunday, 1=Monday..)

Month and Day in some crontabs also accepst strings like Dec, Mon etc.